# How to use "endText" in this case?

Tags: java, android, string

I'm trying to use `endText` but I'm not sure how to make it accessible from one public void to another.

[image]

Comment: You have variable `endText` in (atleast) two methods. Which one of them, if any, do you want? And please post code as text, not image.

Comment: @Guy the one after //display order summary on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep String endText; out of all the methods.
And where you are using it assign value as endText = ---;

Now it will be accessible.

Hope it helps

Comment: yeey thanks! :D 
I was thinking about this problem like for 30 minutes and it was so simple.